# How to fix this old RStudio theme?

Tags: rstudio

it's driving me nuts, I want to fix [this RStudio theme](https://github.com/patrickshox/Mojave-Dark-RStudio-Theme).
I really love it, but some of the menus are white background with white font, which is "a bit" hard to read. I tried the `Inspect Element` function, but I just can't orientate In this HTML code. [Here is my Posit thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-anyone-know-how-to-update-the-appearance-of-that-theme/182384/6).

I guess there must somewhere be a global background color that is set to `white`. I just don't find it. maybe someone can guide me and give me a hint.

[image]